# Semantic UI checkbox events not triggering after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, semantic-ui, jquery-events

I'm using Semantic UI 2.1 and I have a problem. I have three slider checkboxes in my page. They all have the same class and I can initialize them all at once. They each contain a `data-*` attribute that I need to send to the server with AJAX calls.

Here's the problem:

After the first time an AJAX call is finished, the events for checkbox no longer work. I know that the events are bound to the DOM and with the change of DOM they won't update but is there any way around it?

Here's a very simple version of my page:

```
<html>
<body id="body">
<!-- First Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="0" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>
<!-- Second Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="2" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>
<!-- Third Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="3" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>

<button class="button-action">Do Stuff</button>

</body>
<script>
$('.checkbox.comment').checkbox().checkbox({
    onChecked: function () {
        // This is only called before ajax reload, after ajax, it just won't
        console.log("onChecked called");
    },
    onUnchecked: function () {
        // This too is only called before ajax reload
        console.log("onUnchecked called");
    }
});

$(document).delegate('.button-action', 'click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        // Noraml ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // Reload
            $('#body').load(document.URL + ' #body');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put your checkbox event listener inside a function and call that function each time it reload your page or when you make changes in the document DOM. I've attached a sample code below for reference.

```js
function Checkbox_eventlistener(){
  $('.checkbox.comment').checkbox().checkbox({
        onChecked: function () {
            // This is only called before ajax reload, after ajax, it just won't
            console.log("onChecked called");
        },
        onUnchecked: function () {
            // This too is only called before ajax reload
            console.log("onUnchecked called");
        }
  });
}

$(document).delegate('.button-action', 'click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        // Noraml ajax parameters
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // Reload
            $('#body').load(document.URL + ' #body');
            Checkbox_eventlistener();
        }
    });
});

$(function(){
  Checkbox_eventlistener();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<!-- First Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="0" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>
<!-- Second Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="2" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>
<!-- Third Element -->
<div class="ui fitted slider checkbox comment">
    <input data-status="3" type="checkbox"> <label></label>
</div>

<button class="button-action">Do Stuff</button>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. The first time it's fine but after page reload the buttons don't do anything.

Comment: Are you required to put selector suffix expression in your **.load()** method? As per JQuery documentation:

_"When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed."_  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Without that ` + ' #body'` part, it makes a mess, it duplicates the `body`. I can confirm that without that selector to the end of the url, it works but also duplicates the #body. element

Comment: Have you tried alternative methods other than **.load()**? Like **.html()** instead?

Comment: I don't think `html()` method can do the stuff `load()` can.. Don't know how it could be useful in my case.